# Excel VBA TRIM macro not trimming email addresses

Tags: string, vba, excel, trim

I have a macro that trims all cells in the currently selected column, when I use it on normal text, names, postcodes etc it works just fine, but when its used to trim an email address column it isn't removing trailing spaces.

' This needs trimming ' becomes 'This needs trimming' but
'thisneeds@trimming.to ' stays as 'thisneeds@trimming.to '.

This is the macro,

```
Dim mycell
mycell = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select

    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to trim column " & Split(mycell, "$")(1) & "?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim arrData() As Variant
Dim arrReturnData() As Variant
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

  lRows = Selection.Rows.Count
  lCols = Selection.Columns.Count

  ReDim arrData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)
  ReDim arrReturnData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)

  Set rng = Selection
  arrData = rng.Value

  For j = 1 To lCols
    For i = 1 To lRows
      arrReturnData(i, j) = Trim(arrData(i, j))
    Next i
  Next j

  rng.Value = arrReturnData

  Set rng = Nothing

Range(mycell).Select
```

I can't understand why it works for every column but not email addresses.

Comment: Probably some of your "spaces" are actually non-break spaces (ascii code 160)

Comment: You need to click Alt-F11 and open the VBA editor. Paste the code into it. And then in the excel sheet, simply type "=TrimStr(" like a normal formula. Please lookup more ways to use VBA, it's very helpful.

Comment: I dont want to type anything into the excel sheet. Rows of data are imported and need trimming without me inputting anything to the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get by without reinventing the wheel.

Please use this function as sample code to proceed.

```
Public Function TrimStr(inputStr As String) As String
    TrimStr = WorksheetFunction.Trim(inputStr)
End Function
```

I have tried it with your example and others, and all sorts of spaces are removed.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion however my VBA knowledge is still lacking so I am struggling to integrate this as an alternative to my code?